# Are there ways to change your primary spellcasting ability other than the feats in Legends of the Twins?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

Going through Legends of the Twins I found a pair of feats that allow Divine casters to switch to either Intelligence or Charisma as their primary spellcasting ability in lieu of Wisdom.

This made me wonder though: are there other ways to change your primary spellcasting ability? I'm looking for all the options available for both Arcane and Divine casters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While it is 3rd party content and not WoTC material, there is a feat in the book "Bastards and Bloodlines" that allows for this:

> **LOST TRADITION [GENERAL]**
>
> You are descended from a group of spellcasters who had very different ways of mastering magic, and you follow in their tradition.
>   Benefits: Choose one spellcasting class. You may change which ability score governs spellcasting with that class. That ability cannot be changed again.
>
> For example, Meishel Ellazen is a houri cleric. She takes the Lost Tradition feat and chooses to base her clerical spellcasting on Charisma instead of Wisdom. She now uses her Charisma score to determine her bonus spells, spell save DCs, maximum spell level she may cast, and any other calculation regarding her cleric spells.
>   Special: You can take this feat only at 1st level.

As far as I am aware, that (other than some twisted way of using a wish spell or similar) is the only way for any spell casting class to change their primary base stat for spellcasting.

Comment: Note how this feat does not have any restrictions to mental attributes, in case you want to screw over your party with Dragons using Str-based Sorcerer casting...

Comment: I have heard of this feat in relation to the ways of the Muscle Wizards, but I didn't know that it was from some kind of third party book.

Comment: @ThomasJacobs: The problem of this feat is that the classes were "balanced" by using different abilities to power different mechanics so that you would not be able to use the same ability for everything. A Cleric using Charisma instead of Wisdom, for example, powers with a single ability both its Divine Spell and its Undead Turning/Social Skills. And of course, basing off Strength/Dexterity/Constitution opens up another whole can of worms.